# Attachment thumbnail in lightning component

Tags: lightning, attachment

I'm wondering how can i display my attachment and its miniature in front of the title in lightning component ? is there a component that does the job ?

Here is an example : 
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify when you say miniature, if you are referring to see a preview of the file in a lightning component?

Comment: It's like what is shown in the picture , like an avatar but its displays a preview of the attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lightning:fileCard`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/documentation) here which does exactly what you want, i.e., displays a preview of a file.

> A `lightning:fileCard` component displays a preview of a file.
>
> ...
>
> The file type determines the icon used on the file preview and caption area.

The component is used as below, where the `fileId` value must be a valid 15 character ContentDocument ID.

```
<lightning:fileCard fileId="xxxx" description="Description"/>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why its doesnt work it shows me no preview available ?

Comment: Which experience are you viewing the file in? You may like to check the documentation to see if that may be the reason

Comment: I'm using it in opportunity object and the file is stored in attachments

Comment: Okay I think the component only supports [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)